# Git merging sub branches before merging to master

Tags: git, merge

I have branch A . I know that it is save but because of some procedures I can't merge it to master branch(in my case it is code review I need to wait some of my colleagues to review my code ).  Now I need to start another feature let say this one is branch B.

Branch B depends on some features that I implemented in branch A. But since I couldn't merge A to master, B does not has this features.

Is it a good idea in my case to merge branch A directly to branch B even before merging A to master?

Comment: How else would you get the features you need?

Comment: Of course I can delay starting the task B until A is merged to master. But the question in my mind if I merge A to B now than will I face with conflict when I change B .

Comment: Git will merge B back into master just fine. It will realize that there are no changes in the parts that were modified in A if you merge A into B and master.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create new branch `B` from branch `A` (not "merge `A` directly to branch `B`"):

```
git branch B A
git checkout B
```

Do your work. After branch `A` is merged to `master`, use `rebase`:

```
git checkout B
git rebase master
```

Continue to work on branch `B`

Comment: Can you please explain what does rebase do?

Comment: I can't explain better: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase